# Bash: How to check if dynamic env variable is set?

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I'm writing a script where I want to dynamically create an environment variable name, and check if it has been set.

```
#!/bin/bash

#######################################
# Builds options string
# Globals:
#   JVM_OPTS_DIR
# Arguments:
#   1. Options env variable name
#   2. File containing options defaults
# Returns:
#   Options
#######################################
function buildOpts() {
  declare -n opts=$1
  declare -n excludeOpts="EXCLUDE_$1"
  local -r optsFile=$2
  local x=
  if [ -z ${excludeOpts+x} ]; then
    while read -r o; do
      if [ -n "${o// }" ]; then
        x+=" $o"
      fi
    done <"$JVM_OPTS_DIR/$optsFile"
  fi
  if [ -n "$opts" ]; then
    for o in $opts; do
      x+=" $o"
    done
  fi
  printf '%s' "$x"
}

# https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html

# Standard options
stdOpts=$(buildOpts STD_OPTS std.opts)

...

javaCmd="java $stdOpts $nonStdOpts $advRtOpts $advCompOpts $advServOpts $advGcOpts -jar $APP_DIR/app.jar"

printf '%s' "$javaCmd"

# eval $javaCmd "$@"
```

The above script serves as a Docker entrypoint

```
docker build -t jdk . && docker run --rm -it jdk -e APP_NAME=test -e APP_LOG_DIR=test -e APP_DIR=test -e STD_OPTS='a b' -e EXCLUDE_STD_OPTS=true
```

However, I don't see `a` and `b` included in the `javaCmd`, neither do I see the `EXCLUDE` working. Basically, none of the `if` conditions in function `buildOpts` are working.

I'm a backend programmer, and not a Bash wizard. Help.

Comment: You need to put the envs flags before the image name. Syntax of `docker run` is: `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]`. Anything after the image name will be treated as `[COMMAND][ARG...]`.

Comment: @Yuankun You're right. If you care to put that as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the envs flags before the image name.

Syntax of `docker run` is:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Anything after the image name will be treated as `[COMMAND][ARG...]`